# Can I test when IOS4 AVPlayer seekToTime completes?

Tags: video, ios4, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using `AVFoundation` to implement an `AVPlayer`. I want to loop a video clip continuously, so I register an `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` to call this method:

```
- (void)player1ItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{ 
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
       ^{
        [player1 seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; 
        [player1 play];
       });
}
```

It works some of the time, but eventually play stops, presumably because of asynchronous completion of the `seekToTime`. How can I make this code bullet-proof?

Answer (score 5):

I have now fixed this by setting the AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd property of the AVPlayer to AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone - the default was AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause. The AVPlayer no longer pauses at the end of the clip, so play does not have to be restarted. Also found that it was unnecessary to dispatch the seekToTime to the main queue.

Answer (score 5):

```
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[player currentItem]];

(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
 [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Controller.h add

```
AVPlayer *myplayer;
```

in Controller.m add

```
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[myplayer currentItem]];
[myplayer play];
```

and add function from selector

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [notification object];
[playerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[myplayer play];
```

}

This is help me for looping video, but you need cache it some how (for smooth loop)

Comment: heh, some time stop %( play when play count is 2,5,6,11 :(

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)playLogo {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" 
                                                 ofType:@"m4v" 
                                            inDirectory:@"../Documents"];

self.myplayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
self.myplayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.myplayerItem];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.myplayer currentItem]];
[videoView setPlayer:self.myplayer];
[videoView setAlpha:0.5f];
[self.myplayer play]; }

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
[videoView setAlpha:0.0f];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
                                              object:[self.myplayer currentItem]];
[self playLogo];    }
```